# Create individual objects based on json response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to take a json response and create as many objects that are contained in the response. Based on the text below, I want variable to be based on "testuser1" and the next variable to be based on "testuser2", and so on. Im able to convert the response to a dictionary but I'm sure how to count the objects and make variables out of each so I can refer and change them later in the code.

```
{'Accounts': 
    [
      {'Name': 'testuser1', 
       'Username': 'testuser1', 
       'Email': 'test1@example.com'}, 
      {'Name': 'testuser2', 
       'Username': 'testuser2', 
       'Email': 'test2@example.com'}
    ]
```

Basically, I want to count and create as many objects that are in the response. I don't want to use the split function to look for the {}. For example: $var1 = {'Name': 'testuser1', 'Username': 'testuser2=1', 'Email': 'test1@example.com'} and $var2 = {'Name': 'testuser2', 'Username': 'testuser2', 'Email': 'test2@example.com'}

Comment: Just leave them in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I think about this problem, I believe I'm approaching it wrong. I shouldn't be trying to convert this data because I can refer to each element of the dictionary. Converting to a variable is redundant.

Thanks for everyones help with a noob python approach and problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for python 3:

```
import json

response = ...  # Your json response
d = json.loads(response)
obj_list = []

total_obj = len(d['Accounts'])

for index in range(tot_obj):
    obj_list.append(d['Accounts'][index])

var1 = obj_list[0]  # Optionally, var1 = d['Accounts'][0]
var2 = obj_list[1]
```

The method `json.loads()` converts a `string` to `dictionary` while `json.dumps()` does that the other way round.

Check out this documentation to know more: [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

You can store the variables in a list which could be accessed using indices.

Comment: Yes, but how can I create variables of each subdirectory of "Accounts"? Based on example above it should create 2 variables. For example: $var1 = {'Name': 'testuser1', 'Username': 'testuser2=1', 'Email': 'test1@example.com'} and $var2 = {'Name': 'testuser2', 'Username': 'testuser2', 'Email': 'test2@example.com'}